# How Do I Enable Drag-and-Drop in Tiki Wiki Kanban Boards?

Tags: kanban, tiki-wiki

I am trying to set up Kanban boards in Tiki Wiki, and have successfully enabled the plugin via the profile installer. I am currently running Tiki Wiki 24.1vcs with a company intranet profile.

However, I am unable to drag-and-drop the Kanban cards in the sample board like the plugin documentation describes: https://doc.tiki.org/PluginKanban.

In fact, the only way I can make any edits to the Kanban cards is to open their tracker items and make changes there. This is contrary to one of the cards in the board that says it was edited directly in the Kanban UI.

[image]

I have tried using Chrome, Firefox, MS Edge, and disabling all browser plugins to no avail. I also ensured that API Access, Always Load Vue.js, and Enable Vue.js were enabled in the settings.

Is there some other setting or plugin I am missing? Any help would be appreciated.